# Cannot create the react app , found 1 low severity vulnerability

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, node-modules, create-react-app

while creating app using box ** npx create-react-app my-app**,
After that CMD is freezed, nothing is happened.even after waiting more than 30mins nothing happened.

**Only node modules, package.json, package.lock.json is created.no others files created.**

I'm using windows 10 64bit
Node version 12.18.3 LTS
NPM version 6.14.6

TIA

Comment: Happened to me as well while ago after clean installation. I killed the process tried 2 more times and it magically started working (but on a linux instead of windows).

Comment: @MatusDubrava you just kill the process or did you do anything for this issue.

Comment: I just killed it and rerun it twice and it started working and I haven't had any problems since then so I thought that it was just a glitch on my side and wasn't digging into it. (but I remember than only those files that you have mentioned were created when I was experiencing this so it may be similar issue)

Answer (score 0):

If your terminal is stopped for vulnerability or other any kind of thing, you have to resume the terminal process. Open [Resource Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuZ0r.png) by pressing [Windows key + r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTQ55.png) to open the Run dialog box, then type the resmon.exe command. There you find different types of processes, running in the background. You have to find the cmd process or the terminal process there. You will see that the process is suspended. Right-click on the process and resume it. As many times your terminal gets stuck, you have to resume that process in resource monitor.
I hope it will help ☺ ☺.